# One component at the left with defined width and another one at its right taking the rest of the horizontal space

Tags: react-native, layout

I'm trying to make an component which has two TextInput's :

- Number of the street
- Name of the street

I want the first one to have a width of 35 and the second one to fill the remaining space horizontally.

How would you do that ?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import FormInput from "./FormInput"

export default class NoStreetInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <FormInput style={{container: {width: 35}}} placeholder="N°" defaultValue="4"/>
                <FormInput style={{container: {flexGrow: 1}}} placeholder="Addresse" defaultValue="Chemin Du Moulin" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

My FormInput component (just in case) :

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCorrect={false}
                defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                password={password}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
            />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out what was missing. I begin with React Native and I thought I could access my children style properties of my custom component without adding a props.
I forgot to create a props for my component so that it can take a style from outside.

I finally made it like that :

style={{..}} is now a props in my custom component (see 2nd code)

```
export default class NoStreetInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <FormInput style={{flex:0, width:35}} placeholder={this.props.placeholderNo}
                           defaultValue={this.props.defaultValueNo} width="35" keyboardType="number-pad" upperLabel="No"/>
                <FormInput style={{flex:1}} placeholder={this.props.placeholderStree}
                           defaultValue={this.props.defaultValueStreet} upperLabel="Rue" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

My custom component (it's a bit different than before but the logic is the same) :

```
<View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
            <Text style={[styles.upperLabel, customStyle]}>{upperLabel}</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={[styles.textInput, this.props.textInputStyle]}
                autoCorrect={false}
                defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
                value={text}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                password={password}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
                maxLength={maxLength}
                onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
                onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmitEditing}
            />
</View>
```

style={[styles.textInput, this.props.textInputStyle]} allows me to have a default style for my component, which can be overriden by this.props.textInputStyle :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will simply need to have one `TextInput`'s width set to 35 (which you did), and the other's `TextInput` with its `flex` attribute set to 1:

```
<View 
  style={{
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}
>
  <TextInput value="No" style={{ width: 35 }} />
  <TextInput value="Street Name" style={{ flex: 1 }} />
</View>
```

(obviously your styling should be kept inside a StyleSheet instead, but you get the point)

[Here's a working example](https://snack.expo.io/@eveningkid/double-textinput)